# Is it possible to have a button in a custom UITableViewCell that references a selector in it

Tags: ios, ios7

I am not a full-time iOS dev, so this may be simple. I have the following in a custom UITableViewCell but it doesn't seem to be working. The vast majority have the selector being in the Controller. Is this possible? What am I doing wrong here?

In my custom UITableViewCell

```
-(void)updateCell:(NSDictionary *)content
{
  
  UILabel *mainLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0f, 20.0f)];
  mainLabel.text=[content objectForKey:@"name"];
  [self.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];
  
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [button addTarget:self
             action:@selector(aMethod:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 50.0f, 20.0f);
  [self.contentView addSubview:button];
}

-(void)aMethod:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"here is a method");
}
```

which is called in my ViewController in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

### Edit

Basically I would like to get an expanded content effect similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/bso3sa07/

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ContentCell.h"

@interface ViewController (){
  NSMutableArray *_data;
  
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
  
  
  self.tableView.dataSource=self;
  self.tableView.delegate=self;
  
  NSDictionary *obj1=@{@"name":@"Julie"};
  NSDictionary *obj2=@{@"name":@"Melissa"};
  
  _data=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [_data addObject:obj1];
  [_data addObject:obj2];
  
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [_data count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  id tmpCell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  ContentCell *cell=(ContentCell *)tmpCell;
  return cell.height;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"ContentCell";
  ContentCell *cell = (ContentCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  cell = [[ContentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  [cell updateCell:[_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  
  
  UIButton *moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [moreButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(vcSelector)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [moreButton setTitle:@"vcMore" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(200.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 20.0f);
  [cell.contentView addSubview:moreButton];
  
  
  return cell;
}

-(void)vcSelector
{
  NSLog(@"hello from vcSelector");
  // lets get a reference to that specific cell
  // how would I expand that specific cell?
  /*
   id tmpCell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   ContentCell *cell=(ContentCell *)tmpCell;
   return cell.height;
   */
  
}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

ContentCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ContentCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat height;
-(void)updateCell:(NSDictionary *)obj;
@end
```

ContentCell.m

```
#import "ContentCell.h"



@implementation ContentCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

-(void)updateCell:(NSDictionary *)content
{
  self.height=60.0f;
  UILabel *mainLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0f, 20.0f)];
  mainLabel.text=[content objectForKey:@"name"];
  mainLabel.layer.borderColor=[UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
  mainLabel.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
  [self.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];
  
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [button addTarget:self
             action:@selector(aMethod:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 20.0f);
  [self.contentView addSubview:button];
  
}


-(void)aMethod:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"here is a method");
  UIView *pushView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 50.0f, 300.0f, 5.0f)];
  [pushView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  [self.contentView addSubview:pushView];
  self.height=90.0f;
  
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: Yeah this is entirely possible and shouldn't take long to debug. Do you want buttons on every cell?

Comment: yes, I would - I think my selector is set up incorrectly

Comment: In the above code the method you're calling is inside the custom cell object. Are you trying to execute the code inside the cell object, or do you want to do some function inside the table view? Can you give more details about what the method is going to do?

Comment: ok thx - basically, we are going to show another view that is like 'send a comment' on this item so it would need to expand that current custom view down. the dev who started this said that the uitableview will manage the expansion down of the other parts. so in short, show more content which will then be dismissed.

Comment: hmmm that's a bit more complicated, because your table view will need to update the height in heightForRowAtIndexPath accordingly. Do you have any code in the heightForRow.. method of your table view?

Comment: What isn't working here? is `aMethod:` not getting called?

Comment: yes, aMethod isn't being called. I am not sure if the custom UITableViweCell doesn't support this or whether I just some foolish syntax issue (foolish on my part).

Comment: Is the button visible in the cell?

Comment: Showing us the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath might be helpful, this could potentially be a reuse thing, but not too sure.

Comment: the `@selector` seems to be set up right as far as I can read. That being said, I can't test it where I am right now. But I see no problem with the `@selector`.

Comment: yes Mike, it is visible - something else is blowing up at work; have to switch over. will work on tonight :) thx

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    // Check if button exist already
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:555];
    // if not - create new one
    if (!button)
    {
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.tag = 555;
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 50.0f, 20.0f);
        [cell addSubview:button];
    }

    // update title and selector if required
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return cell;
}
```